# In Tournament Poker, how do you play 4 handed on a 7 table max game, with 2 tables left?

Tags: tournament, final-table

So I had this situation that I felt totally lost in to my normal game. This is just a home online game with ~25-35 people. Normally we play 9 hand max table.

I got to the final 9 people, but because its a 7 handed max game we were playing with 4 people. I was table lead with ~15 BB. Normally we'd be in a final table situation, but now there's 4 people left, but ICM isn't a factor. The blinds are raising so that every hand the final 4 people are redistributing the stacks at the table.

ICM is no longer a factor, but the hands come quickly with small amount of people. I didn't know how to act at the table as normally at this point there's a full final 9 table OR there's 4 people left in the entire tournament, where ICM plays a factor.

Any advice on how to play in this situation?

Comment: Why is ICM no longer a factor? It's a tournament, with 9 players left, one table of 5 and another of 4. I don't know why ICM stopped being a factor. Also extra note, if you're playing a strategy that relies only on ICM, you're missing so much. ICM ignores important things like skill, position, blinds, or really any poker actually being played. It's great as a guide on how we should adjust our play and action, it's fantastic if you want to make a fair chop or deal.

Comment: How many players are going to be paid?